# Error catch... The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned t

Tags: flutter

I"m tring to catch standard exception with the following code:

```
 @override
  Stream<LoginState> mapEventToState(LoginEvent event) async* {
    if (event is LoginUsernameChanged) {
      yield state.copyWith(username: event.username);
    } else if (event is LoginPasswordChanged) {
      yield state.copyWith(password: event.password);
    } else if (event is Loginsubmitted) {
      yield state.copyWith(formStatus: state.formStatus);
      try {
        await authRepo.login();
        yield state.copyWith(formStatus: SubmissionSuccess());
        
      } catch (e) {
        yield state.copyWith(formStatus:  SubmissionFailed(e));
      }
    }
  }
```

The SubmissionFailed class code is :

```
class SubmissionFailed extends FromSubmissionStatus {
  final Exception exception;
  **SubmissionFailed(this.exception);**
}
```

How ever the compiler say:

```
The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Exception'.
```

Why?
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter in `try-catch` is an Object, not necessarily an exception. Depending on how `await authRepo.login();` handles exceptions, that will be the type of `e` in the `try-catch`

In one of the examples [here](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await), you can see it throws a `String` instead of an `exception`

```
Future<void> printOrderMessage() async {
  try {
    print('Awaiting user order...');
    var order = await fetchUserOrder();
    print(order);
  } catch (err) {

    // You can see the runtimeType of err is a String 
    // because fetchUserOrder throws a String

    print('Caught error: $err');
  }
}

Future<String> fetchUserOrder() {
  // Imagine that this function is more complex.
  var str = Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 4),

      // Here it throws a string, not an exception. 
      // You could throw the exception here

      () => throw 'Cannot locate user order');
  return str;
}

Future<void> main() async {
  await printOrderMessage();
}
```